# Not able to import the project in Android Studio

Tags: android, git, android-studio, intellij-idea, version-control

Importing new projects giving error for me.

[image: Error Message]

**My Android Studio Setup:**

Android Studio 3.2.1
Build #AI-181.5540.7.32.5056338, built on October 9, 2018
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1136-b06 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Windows 10 10.0

Previously I was able to import with same setup but from last two days I am facing this.

Thanks in Advance !

Comment: @PSandeshBaliga I have tried Invalidate Caches/Restart, but still facing same

Comment: Try reinstalling AS.

Answer (score 0):

Can you delete ".AndroidStudio" folder from C:/Users/*your_username*/.AndroidStudio and try?

This looks like VCS cache issue of android studio.